# rsync wants to resend files after a recent run

Tags: directory, rsync

I am using `rsync` to keep two directories in sync. Specifically I ran:

```
rsync -avz /path/to/src /path/to/dest
```

After this command finished, I ran:

```
rsync --dry-run -avz /path/to/src /path/to/dest
```

but the `dry-run` version still outputs all the files in the `src` directory as if it wants to resend them. What's going on? Shouldn't `dest` be perfectly up to date with `src`?

Comment: Is the remote machine any kind of POSIX system? (Linux, BSD, Unix?) If it's some kind of non-POSIX NAS, for example, it probably won't understand POSIX permissions, so there will be information loss on every rsync, fooling rsync into thinking that it still has work to do on each pass.

Comment: Also, are you certain you are seeing *file* names in the output of the second command? If it's just directory names, that's normal.

Comment: @WarrenYoung definitely seeing file names. I think the remote machine is running CentOS

Comment: And is the filesystem on the remote side a fully POSIX compatible file system? A CentOS box sharing an NTFS or FAT partition still falls into the same class as non-POSIX NAS systems.

Comment: how can i check this? it's a large computing cluster

Comment: If you can `rsync` to the machine, you can probably `ssh` to it as well. Therefore, `ssh` in and say `mount`, or examine `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: `dest` is actually a shared directory so i have no idea which specific machine the hard disk is actually on (ie there is nothing to `ssh` to)... ie the directory is visible from every node on the system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39097/discussion-between-warren-young-and-alex).

Comment: You will get very few of the benefits of `rsync` in this scenario as it see both source and destination in the same filesystem. Is it possible that the clock for your remote server is different to the clock on your local server by more than a second? If so, try turning off timestamps with `--no-times` and seeing if that resolves the problem. The solution here would then be to fix the clocks, or failing that use the ` --modify-window=N` parameter to `rsync` to tell it to ignore an offset of N seconds. (If this works for you I'll convert this comment to an answer.)

Answer (score 5):

You can usefully add the `-i` option to rsync to make it show you why it wants to copy the file again. For example, you might see

```
 .f...po.... somefilename
```

which means the remote file has different **p**ermissions and **o**wner.  One solution is to use `--size-only` to only compare the sizes of files, but obviously this  might cause some changed files not to be sent. You can also add `-c` to compare checksums, which requires more effort at both ends.